# Android, searchview in custom popup no text entered

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-view, searchview

I have a searchview within a custom popup window, with a listview below.

I'm trying implement a standard searchview scenario - typing text into the searchview will filter what is displayed within the list view.

For some reason, I am unable to enter text within the searchview.
The soft keyboard displays fine, but when I type, no text is entered.

```
public void display(final LayoutInflater inflater, int layout, final View anchor, ArrayList<String> docs, String currentDoc){   
    LinearLayout popupView = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(layout, null);
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(mList == null){
        mList = (ListView)popupView.findViewById(R.id.doc_pop_list);
    }
    mDocuments = docs;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mContext, R.layout.list_item,docs);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);

    searchDocs=(SearchView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.doc_list_search);
    searchDocs.requestFocus();
    searchDocs.setQuery("", false);
    searchDocs.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
          @Override
          public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
          }
          @Override
          public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                   adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            return false;
          }
        });
    mList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            docName = mList.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            mWindow.dismiss();                  
            mListener.docSelected(docName.toString());  

        }

    });

    Button dismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.button_docs_close);
    dismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
            mWindow.dismiss();

        }

    });
```

See above java code;

In my xml I have a custom listview item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/text1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:textColor="#000000" />
```

And this is displayed within this layout:

```
  <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/doc_list_search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:queryHint="Search documents..." >

    </SearchView>
</RelativeLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/doc_pop_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="420dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/doclist_close"
    android:layout_below="@+id/docs_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_docs_close"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:text="@string/close"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
.....
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you try logging content of searchview from onQueryTextChange when you type something? I just want to rule rule out display issue.

EDIT:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    RelativeLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        display();
    }

    public void display(){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
        layout.addView(view);

        SearchView searchDocs=(SearchView) view.findViewById(R.id.doc_list_search);
        searchDocs.requestFocus();
        searchDocs.setQuery("", false);
        searchDocs.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Test","input");
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I tried this, I couldn't get any output to logcat. I added a few breakpoints to see could I capture when the text was changing, and nothing.

Comment: Ok I tested your code (just basic functionality) and input is shown fine. Maybe it will help you (view edited answer).

Comment: Hey, thanks, I've tried the above, well, refactoring it to suit how I'm using, but kept the essentials the same. Still nothing happening.  Now, my custom popup view is displayed over the soft keyboard, CSS z-index per-say, do you think this is relevant? I'm using the same implementation as above in a standalone activity and it functions fine. It's when it's implemented within this custom view it doesn't function.

Comment: Interesting... try to show the keyboard by clicking on the searchview not programatically. Maybe there is a focus issue with searchview.

Comment: Yeah I had that initially, but I needed to hide the keyboard when clicking the close button as for some reason the searchview still had focus when I dismissed the view. It didn't make any difference. I'll keep toying with it, thanks for your help though

Comment: Sorry I couldnt be more help. Last thing I tried was searchDocs.setIconified(false);
searchDocs.requestFocus(); without any additional keyboard operation ... and if there is a focus problem on closing the window, try clearFocus maybe... Good luck